# Django, Extend BaseUserManager,

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm trying to extend Django's `BaseUserManager`, so when you create a super user, I'm checking if an `organization` exists (if not create one) and then assign the user to it with a `ForeignKey`.

The error I'm gettting is:

```
Creating Demo Data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 55, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 160, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/project/accounts/models.py", line 36, in create_superuser
    user = self.create_user(email, password=password)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/project/accounts/models.py", line 20, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 698, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 731, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 920, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 129, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 134, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 282, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 768, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 929, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1125, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 893, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 369, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 120, in raise_mysql_exception
    _check_mysql_exception(errinfo)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 112, in _check_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errorvalue)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, u"Column 'organization_id' cannot be null")
```

I guess it's something that has do with the models?

**Accounts**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from project.organizations.models import Organization

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        ...

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):

        print "Creating Demo Data..."

        if Organization.objects.filter(name="Demo Inc.").count() < 1:
            organization = Organization.objects.create(name="Demo Inc.")
            organization.save()
            print "Demo data created successfully!"
        else:
            organization = Organization.objects.all().first()

        user = self.create_user(email, password=password)
        user.organization = organization
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

**User model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # custom User models must have an integer PK
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name="users")
```

**Organizations**

```
class Organization(models.Model):

    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, auto=True, db_index=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. And where is UUIDField from?

Comment: I've added the full traceback. Also the `UUIDField` is coming from `from uuidfield import UUIDField` which is installed from pypi (`django-uuidfield==0.5.0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs here:

```
user = self.create_user(email, password=password)
```

This method saves the newly created user with `organization` set to `None`. Move the checking and assigning of an organization from the `create_superuser()` into the `create_user()`.

Comment: That sounds right. What I was trying to achieve though(and that's why I placed it under `createsuperuser` is to assign only admins to the default one.

Comment: When you will create regular user in the admin the `create_user()` method will be called.  So you you have two options: 1. set the default `organization` for all users or 2. add `null=True` attribute to the `organization` foreign key.

Comment: I finally went for no.2 which seems more appropriate (users having no companies - instead of all users having a default company). Thanks!